# Testing python package modules from within the package

Tags: python, automated-tests

I would like to test my Python package from a test module contained within the package, like so

```
/pkg
| __init__.py
| mod.py
| /test
| | test_mod.py
```

with files that look like

```
#mod.py
def somefunc():
    ...

#test_mod.py
def test_somefunc():
    ...
```

My question is 'What existing Python testing packages are best-suited to this type of file structure?' I have used nose in the past, but from what I can tell it is mostly suited to testing modules that are not embedded within the package being tested...although I admit I'm pretty new to this package thing.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can still run `nosetests` and it will work just fine. Have you _tried_ it?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here, Pretty much all testing frameworks, even the builtin unittest, work.